# Is output parameter a string or date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb6

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestDate (bookingdate datetime)
INSERT INTO TestDate VALUES ('2013-10-04')
```

Please see the ADODB recordset below:

```
rs.open "SELECT bookingdate FROM TestDate"
If rs("bookingdate") > dateadd("yyyy", -6, Now)
  msgbox("test")
end if
```

The msgbox always appears regardless of what the date in the database is.

I believe I have to do this:

```
If datevalue(rs("bookingdate")) > dateadd("yyyy", -6, Now)
  msgbox("test")
end if
```

Then the messagebox only appears if the booking date is within the last six years.

Is bookingdate treated as a string in the first code fragment?

I believe the following webpage would give me the answer: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp.  However, it says Internal Server Error.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263402(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: It would have been far better to remove the extraneous tags than to edit the title of this post.  This way we have no idea what the context of the question actually is since there's a whole "ransom note" of tags used.  BTW: This was a VB6 question.

Comment: Add an `Else` statement inside your `If` statement and show a message with the value when the if fails. `Else MsgBox "Date = " & rs("bookingdate").Value`

Answer (score 2):

You should never write code like this anyway:

```
If rs("bookingdate") > DateAdd("yyyy", -6, Now)
```

Instead get in the habit of not relying on the default property, which can backfire on you depending on the usage context.  Preferable:

```
If rs("bookingdate").Value > DateAdd("yyyy", -6, Now)
```

But a huge piece you left out of the puzzle is what DBMS you are using.  Some use some pretty funky data types and call them `DATETIME` so you probably want to look at both the ADO type of the returned Field and try displaying `TypeName(rs("bookingdate").Value)` to see what you're ending up with in your code.

If the returned data is of some type such as `Decimal` or `String` then all bets are off and you need to go through the right set of gyrations to convert it to something useful before attempting comparisons.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for reference to the .value property.  How does ADO decide what data type to return? I guess it looks at the type in the database.  What is the risk of not using .value?

Comment: ADO returns data types based on the database Provider, i.e. Providers are written to map the DMBS data types to ADO types, and then to some extent ADO maps its own types to OLE (Variant) subtypes.  In some code contexts either value-types (number, date, string, etc.) or an Object may both make sense, so if you do not specify .Value you will get the entire Field object assigned instead of Field.Value, and hilarious (or not so hilarious) results can ensue.